# How to serialize an object in C# and prevent tampering?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, serialization, encryption

I have a C# class as follows:

```
public class TestObj
{
    private int intval;
    private string stringval;
    private int[] intarray;
    private string[] stringarray;

    //... public properties not shown here
}
```

I would like to serialize an instance of this class into a string.

In addition:

I will be appending this string as a QueryString param to a URL. So I would like to take some effort to ensure that the string cannot be tampered with easily.

Also, I would like the serialization method to be efficient so the size of the string is minmal.

Any suggestions of specific .NET Framework classes/methods I should use?

Answer (score 4):

1) To serialize:

```
 public String SerializeObject(TestObj object)
 {
        String Serialized = String.Empty;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ( );
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestObj));
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter ( memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8 );
        xs.Serialize (xmlTextWriter, object);
        memoryStream = (MemoryStream) xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
        Serialized = UTF8Encoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        return Serialized;
 }
```

2) To prevent tampering:

- Come up with a secret string, e.g. "MySecretWord".
- Take your serialized object instance as a string, and append the secret word to it.
- Hash the string (e.g. SHA *or use HMAC (as suggested by Remus)* )
- Append the hash to the query string

On the receiving side (which also knows your "MySecretWord" secret string) you strip away the hash, take the original serialized instance, append the known secret string and hash it again. Then compare the two hashes for equality. If they are equal, your string was not modified.

You may need to Url/Base64 Encode your string so it works as a query string. This is also important as you need the query string to arrive exactly as sent.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't address sharing or updating the secret with the destination.  Presumably if he wants to prevent tampering, then the other side needs know how to check for invalid values.  Also, if he uses a predictable secret, someone could tamper with the object and recalculate the hash.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. The CLR provides HMAC signatures out of the box, reviewed by proper cryptographers.

Comment: @Omniwombat: This is surely not a high-security scenario as he's dealing with query string transmission of information. The pure existence of a secret will throw off any 'attacker'. Also, the secret can be chosen to be indefinitely complex which makes the hashing solution scalable to security needs, but in that case I'd rather encrypt the entire string along the line. Either way, for anything tamper-proof he will need access to the destination.

Comment: @Alex Do be careful with terms like "surely not a high-security scenario" and "will throw off any 'attacker'"  We don't know his requirements, and there will never be technology that is guaranteed to thwart _all_ attacks.

(Also, I think you mean "arbitrarily" complex.)

Comment: @Omniwombat: I can leave comments all day criticizing other people's solutions. I have provided him with a solution that works quickly for what I can deduce his requirements are, instead of helping him write the entire thing with OTP supported RSA asynchronous encryption that is bank standard compliant. Key Point: I haven't seen you provide an answer. How about you give us an example of your code magic that will be reusable, highly secure, stable, with low processing overhead, no memory footprint, and maybe it can make coffee too while we're at it.

Answer (score 4):

Sign the stream and add the signature to your query. Use a HMAC signing algorithm, like [HMACSHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(VS.80).aspx). You will need to have a secret between your client and your server to sign and validate the signature.